# Sort image files in ascending order before reading into OCR

Tags: file, sorting, ocr

I want to following loop to work on the filenames so that ocr reads them in ascending manner otherwise the extracted text are not in sequence and then I have to go to the original image and shuffle the extracted chunks.

I have files as `0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0003.jpg, 0004.jpg, 0005.jpg`.

Now the text that gets extracted is in the sequence of `0002.jpg, 0003.jpg, 0005.jpg, 0004.jpg, 0001.jpg`. So I am not able to get the OCR reader to read according to the file number sequence.

I have the following code but it does not work so far sequence is concerned.

```
    if len(a) > 2:
    for fn in os.listdir(a):
        if fn.endswith(".png") or fn.endswith(".jpg"):
            natsort.natsorted(fn)
            x = os.path.join(a, fn)
            rd = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(x), lang='eng') \
                .replace('-\n', '').replace('\n', ' ').encode("ascii", 'ignore')
            tb1.insert('insert', rfi)
            tb1.insert('insert', rd)
            tb1.insert('insert', br)
            count += 1
        else:
            continue

else:
    count -= 1
    messagebox.showinfo(title="PROCEDURAL ERROR",
                        message="Set FOLDER & NEW_NOTE.")
```

the OCR part is ok, I have been successfully using. The problem is that I am not able to fit the sort thing before the execution of the OCR part.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

```
if len(a) > 2:
    xa = []
    for dp, dn, fn in walk(a):
        fn.sort(key=lambda g: int(g.split(".")[0]))
        for s in fn:
            xa.append(a + '/' + s)

    for x in xa:
        rd = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(x), lang='eng') \
            .replace('-\n', '').replace('\n', ' ').encode("ascii", 'ignore')
        tb1.insert('insert', rfi)
        tb1.insert('insert', rd)
        tb1.insert('insert', br)
        count += 1

else:
    count -= 1
    messagebox.showinfo(title="PROCEDURAL ERROR",
                        message="Set FOLDER & NEW_NOTE.")
```